# How to see these characters correctly?

Tags: font

If I view https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%B1%E5%92%8C%E5%88%B6 on macOS 10.12.2 and Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit). It shows a few characters as rectangles with a question mark inside:

[image]

How to make these characters show up correctly?

Comment: I can see the characters fine in Chrome on my iPhone, iOS 10.

Answer (score 1):

No problem seeing them on my iPad, they are Arabic, must be a chrome bug.

[image]

Comment: I can't be convinced that this 'must' be a bug.

Comment: @qazwsx It works fine for me in Safari and Firefox, but not Chrome. I'm also running macOS 10.12.2.

Comment: @qazwsx Let the Chrome folks know they have to fix their browser so it works like all the others.